# ios push certificate development/distribution issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I tested my ios app with development certificate its working when when i run an app with xcode..Later on before submission i created a distribution certificate and changed the push settings with new p12 file and distribution certificate.. pushes were unable to reach the device after that while running from xcode .. my query is

with the distribution certificate..am i able to send pushes only if the app is downloaded from app store? can't i test it by running the app from xcode before submitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to use a distribution certificate to test the production APNS environment. You have a couple of options:

1) Create an ad hoc build.
2) Create your app store build and submit the app to TestFlight. You can then install the app with TestFlight without having to go through the app approval process. This is the best way to test production settings, APNS, CloudKit etc.

You can not debug these production builds in Xcode of course, so you may want to add some other logging etc to diagnose issues you run into.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the IPA using the distribution certificate to test the push notifications in production environment. Its not possible to test the push notifications from the XCode build when you are signing the app with distribution certificate.